# Finding Uniformly Most Powerful(UMP) tests of size $\alpha$

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

Hi I am working on the following problem:

Let $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ be a random sample from a distribution with PDF given by $$f(x\mid\theta)=\frac{c}{\theta^c}x^{c-1}e^{-(\frac{x}{\theta})^c}\,\,\,(\text{Weibull distribution})$$ where $c,\theta>0.$ and $c$ is a constant. Find the Uniformly Most Powerful(UMP) tests of size $\alpha$ for testing $$H_0: \theta\le\theta_0\,\,\,\text{VS.}\,\,\,\,H_1:\theta>\theta_0$$

If anyone wants to look at it I would be happy to provide it here but in short so far I got:

1. $T(\textbf{X})=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^c$ is a complete sufficient statistic
2. $X_i^c\sim \exp(\theta^c)$ and therefore  $T(\textbf{X})=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^c\sim \mathrm{Gamma}(n,\theta^c)$
3. In this step I am stuck. From definition we have $$\alpha=\sup_{\theta\le\theta_0}\beta(\theta)$$ where 
   \begin{align*}
   \beta(\theta)&=E_\theta[\delta(x)]\\
   &=E_\theta[I(T\ge c)]\\
   &=P_\theta[T\ge c]\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\text{where }T\sim \mathrm{Gamma}(n,\theta^c)
   \end{align*}

I could not find the value of $c$ from here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To find the UMP test you should construct the likelihood ration test for the corresponding MP test, i.e., 
$$
\frac{L_(\theta_1;X)}{L_(\theta_0;X)} =  \frac{\theta_0^c}{\theta_1 ^c}\exp\{\sum x_i^c(1/\theta_0 - 1/\theta_1\} > k
$$
where $\theta_1 > \theta_0$. So the LR is monotonic strictly increasing function of the MMS  $\sum x_i^c$, hence the UMP test is 
$$
\delta(X) = \mathrm{1}\{\sum x_i^c > k^*\} .
$$
Then, 
$$ 
E\delta(X) = 1 - P(\sum X_i^c \le k^*) = 1- P(2\theta^c \sum X_i^c \le 2\theta^c k^*),
$$
note that $2\theta^c \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^c \sim Gamma(n, 1/2) = \chi^2_{(2n)}$, thus
$$
E_{\theta_0}\delta(X) = 1- F_{\chi^2(2n)}(2\theta_0^c k^*) =\alpha,
$$
so we get that 
$$
k^* = \frac{\chi_{(2n)}^2(1-\alpha)}{2\theta_0^c}.
$$

Comment: Are you sure about that $Gamma(\frac{n}{2},\frac{1}{2})\stackrel{d}{\to}\chi_n^2$, Isn't it $Gamma(\frac{n}{2},2)$

Comment: I've edited the answer. As far as I know, there is no convergence argument involved. i.e., $Gamma(n, 1/2) \equiv \chi^2_{(2n)}$.